# How to produce a printable watermark?

Tags: image, printing, watermark

How is it possible to make a printable watermark as a pattern that's not visible to a human's eyes? I want to print an watermarked image, take a picture and recognize the message in the invisible watermark.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with "design patterns". Please read the description of tags before you add them to your questions, instead of just randomly using whatever appears to be vaguely related. Using proper tags gets the question to the people who might be able to answer it, properly categorizes the question for searches by future readers, and avoids wasting the time of people who aren't familiar with or interested in the topic.

Comment: So you're looking for a stenographic technique that will survive being run through an inkjet? http://classes.design.ucla.edu/Spring06/159/projects/tina/report.htm

Comment: KenWhite, it was totally unintentional. Thank you for the correction.
@Quentin, it is exactly what I'm looking for.